# Passing a pointer to a list, to a function

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list

Firstly, apologies, I have tried to follow other answers but I cannot get this to work.

I am writing a merge sort program in C, I have a function that takes two pointers to linked lists and creates a new merged linked list out of them and then returns the new list.

I have tried a ton of variations, but I cannot get it to compile. 
This is the definition of the Node struct:

```
    typedef struct node
    {
        int val;
        struct node *next;
    } NODE;
```

Here is the function passing the values:

```
    NODE* splitList(NODE *ptr)
    {
        NODE *startPtr = NULL;
        NODE *endPtr = NULL; 
        NODE *temp  = NULL;
        NODE *temp2 = NULL;

       //fill in startPtr and endPtr with nodes

        }
        return merge(startPtr,endPtr);  //<-- passing startPtr and endPtr

    }
```

This is the header of the function that I am passing the pointers too:

```
    NODE * merge(NODE **start, NODE **end)
```

The error I am getting from the compiler is:

"Conflicting types for 'merge'"

Can anyone tell me where I am going wrong, I know some combination of '&'s and *'s will do the trick and I have tried a lot of combinations!  I don't think I am grasping the underlying behavior so if anyone can help explain that would be great.

Comment: merge(&startPtr,&endPtr)

Comment: I had tried that, but... still get the same error.

Comment: Starting to wonder if the problem is netbeans itself!  But I think the problem is probably me :-)

Comment: Usually, when you get that error, the compiler will show you which lines conflict.  What is the full compiler error you get?  Have you tried putting the declaration of the merge function (`NODE * merge(NODE **start, NODE **end);`) somewhere in the file before you call the function?

Comment: Ooh... thats a good idea I will try that.  The other line of code that the compiler complains about is the $return merge(startPtr,endPtr); It says warning: makes pointer from integer without a cast.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that is annoying.  Yes you were correct, I just needed to have merge before the function that was calling it.  I should have realised that.  Thanks heaps.  Also @OldProgrammer yes, you were right too once I moved the function up the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
merge(&startPtr,&endPtr)
```

This solves the problem . I wrote your code in text editor and compiled it . It compiled it without any problem. It can be possible that merge has been called before it's prototype has been found . Or if you are defining functions first , then maybe you have written splitList before merge. So splitList is unable to find merge function.

Comment: thanks @helptaker, yeah someone commented earlier about moving merge up before the function that is calling it, and the combination of 

        merge(&startPtr,&endPtr)

and moving the function up worked.

Comment: I was typing at that moment so..And thanks for accepting my answer